# Can stored procedures in Snowflake provide a table valued out put, like we get in SQL Server

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can stored procedures in Snowflake provide a table valued out put, like we get in SQL Server? I do not want to store it in a table or view using the stored procedure, rather I want to CALL the stored procedure directly and use the output of the stored procedure in the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL UDTFs

```js
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1(PRFL_NAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE (KEY VARCHAR(16777216), VALUE VARCHAR(16777216))
LANGUAGE SQL
AS 
$$
SELECT '1','2'
$$;

select * from table(func1('somevalue'));
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-table-functions.html

Comment: Hello @Iqra Ijaz, Agreed! the approach mentioned, but in UDF's an input parameter is mandatory, which may not be of need and each and every time the underlying table structure changes I will have to modify the return table of all my UDF's created on top of the tables. I am looking for the options available, where we wrap a group of SQL commands and get an output from a table in it.